# Is there a way I can get an excel file from an email attachment and extract it’s data all within a python script without saving the file locally?

Tags: python, automation, openpyxl

I am writing a script that downloads an excel file from an email and extracts the file’s data to a database. I was able to get the file from the email using imaplib and email libraries but cannot figure out how to load the workbook with openpyxl without saving it locally first.

Comment: What's wrong with saving it locally while it is being processed?
You could save it locally, process it, then remove it with os.remove()

Comment: You may want to check this blog post: https://prabhupant.github.io/2019/07/27/read-excel-sheet-from-gmail-using-python.html

Comment: @NicolasPerez I am trying to host the script on a server not locally.

Comment: @Sheldon Thank you, the blog post used the io module. I will implement that, hopefully it works out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

# get all attachments from INBOX
with MailBox('imap.my.ru').login('acc', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print(att.filename, att.content_type, len(att.payload))
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

I am author

*Working with db is the 2d task